# Run GitLab CI job only if a trigger builds a tag

Tags: gitlab-ci

I want to run a conditional build that is triggered by an api trigger, but only when the ref passed in by the trigger matches a specific regex.

I can imagine 2 ways this could be done:

Logical operators in .gitlab-ci.yml's `only:` directive like so:

```
only:
   - /^staging-v.*$/ AND triggers
```

or

Controlling the result status using return codes

```
script:
   - return 3;
```

would interpreted as "not run" or "skipped"

Am i missing something? I read all the documentation i could find but this scenario is never really explained. Is there maybe a thrid way to do this?

This would be handy with the new `environments` feature of GitLab 8.9
I'm using the latest 8.9.0 gitlab release.

Also the API trigger is needed as i need to pass in more variables from the developer to the build and deploy environment which are dynamic.